# How to store javascript object or JSON in html element usiing html5 data attribute?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, html

I have anchor element.I want to store and retrive the object in it like this way.

```
<a  id ="test" data-val="{key1:val1,key1:val1}"> </a>
```

If I save in this way,while fetching it

`$("#test").data('val')` it gives me string like

`"{key1:val1,key1:val1}"`.

But I am unable to parse it to `json or javascript object` again.
I have tried using `$.parseJSON()`,`JSON.parse()`. But it throwing an error.

How we can achive it without `localstorage or sessionstorage o cookie`

**EDIT** :

After calling `$("#test").data('val')`

I am getting string like this

```
"{'category_slug' : 'featured','tip_slug':'tip-with-all-cats'}"
```

If i have use `$.parseJSON()`or `JSON.parse()` it throwing an error

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token
```

Comment: Note that once you've corrected the format to valid JSON (as pointed out below) jQuery will automatically parse it for you when placing it in the internal `data` cache, so you don't need to call `JSON.parse()` on it. See this example: https://jsfiddle.net/cxznLctj/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because it's not valid JSON.

Valid JSON has quoted keys and uses double quotes to delimit strings. Your example doesn't meet these requirements.

Comment: @RIYAJKHAN My answer still stands. Use double quotes. And make sure your string ends with a `}`

Comment: @RIYAJKHAN single quotes are invalid in json object key.

Comment: Thanks @alex. I got it

Answer (score 1):

That is not valid [JSON](http://www.json.org/), specifically you're missing quotes:

```
{"key1":"val1","key1":"val1"}
```

Comment: That also looks invalid. You're missing at least a trailing `}` and the quotes are single quotes instead of double quotes (but the parser might accept it).